# How can I create videos from images with transitions in C#?

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

Using C# code, I want to take a number of images, add some music and create a video.

I think I can best explain what I want in pseudo-code...:

```
var video = new Video(1080, 1920); //create a video 1080*1920px 
video.AddFrame("C:\temp\frame01.jpg", 2000); //show frame for 2000ms
video.AddTransition(Transitions.Fade, 500); //fade from first to second frame for 500ms
video.AddFrame("C:\temp\frame02.jpg", 1000); //show frame for 1000ms
video.AddTransition(Transitions.Fade, 500); //fade from second to third frame for 500ms
video.AddFrame("C:\temp\frame03.jpg", 2000); //show frame for 2000ms
video.AddSound("C:\temp\mymusic.mp3"); //added from start of video
video.Save("C:\temp\MyAwesomeVideo.avi", Format.MP4);
```

Does something like this exist?

I know there are a couple of older libraries, that can do some stuff with ffmpeg to create slideshows, but I looked at some of them, and they are insanely tricky to get working - and designed for something quite different.

Backstory:

I created a system for a cinema, which every week generates x number of images using movie posters, showtimes etc - and would like to take those images, turn them into a video which will be shared on social media.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly check out [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/).

I have used this previously, and the results were sufficient, especially considering the ease at which you cant construct a video. It uses FFMPEG under the hood, so you don't need to concern yourself with extensive terminal commands.

A possible downside to this is that there is no immediately available option (to my knowledge) to add transitions / keep a still image on the screen for more than one Frame. This would mean you would need to implement those capabilities yourself.

Keep in mind that AForge.NET is licensed under GPLv3

**Check out an example of the [VideoFileWriter](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/4ee1742c-44d3-b250-d6aa-90cd2d606611.htm) class**